# How to block child processes in java and restarting them

Tags: java, process, operating-system

I have two questions:

I need to stop child processes through my main process and then start them again after something happened in my main process.have can I do that?

thanks alot.

Comment: You should separate your questions into two topics.

Comment: To encourage the OP to do the right thing, please DO NOT answer the second part of this question.

Comment: To the OP - please edit your question to get rid of the logically unrelated 2nd part ... or ask someone to do it for you.  Also, if you ask it as a new question, please try to give more details, and an example.  I (for one) cannot work out what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was a long time ago and I was really confused probably that forgot to look for the answers. Thanks but there actually a way to take care of the first part and the answer was Java Remote Method Invocation or simpli RMI:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation

I am going to remove the second part of my question as I simply don't remember what I was on!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean in the above post - I suspect they are different questions and the second is related to Glassfish, which I probably can't answer.

However, for the first I can if you mean threads rather than processes - Java has a wait/notify method pair that used in combination allow you to launch n child threads and wait for them all to complete before continuing in the main process. I think this is what you need, rather than stopping the child process from the main process - in concurrent programming this should never be done as you can't guarantee where you're up to in the child process. Have a look at: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify_4.shtml

Answer (score 0):

For your first part there are some classes in `java.util.concurrent.locks` that may help you. Have a look at `LockSupport`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first part of your question depends on whether the "processes" you are talking about are `Process` or `Thread`.  But in both cases, there is no good way to cause an uncooperative process to "stop".

- In the `Process` case, the OS may well provide support for suspending processes, but the Java Process APIs don't offer this functionality.  So you'd need to resort to non-portable means (e.g. JNI/JNA) to implement this.
- In the `Thread` case, there are methods called `suspend` and `resume`, but they should not be used because they are fundamentally unsafe.  And the Javadoc says so very clearly!

So if you implement a suspend/resume mechanism, you need your processes to participate / cooperate.  In the `Thread` case, you could implement your suspend / resume mechanism using the low-level synchronization primitives, or using something like the [CyclicBarrier](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) class.